# make old version of app free and upload new paid version - itunes

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-app

I already search for this but can't find any useful info about it.

I currently have two paid apps on the App Store. I now have a new version of it with a new feature. Both apps are basically the same and use the universal code both iPhone and iPad but I have added a new feature. What I would like to do is re-upload the current versions as free versions and upload the new versions as paid version. so is this possible to keep old version with make it free and upload new version as paid ? will old version delete if I upload new version of app ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the new version in the app store as well as keep the old versions in there, the new version will need to be uploaded with a different bundle ID as if it was a new app.

You will need to change the pricing of the existing apps in iTunes Connect to the Free tier. The old/existing apps will remain until you remove them from sale.

Comment: if I want to change title detail of app then I can change it or i have to upload new version.(old version is ready for sale) ????

Comment: @pratikbhiyani To change the name/title of the app it must be in an "editable" state, and if it's live already you'll need to create a new version, edit it, upload a new binary, and resubmit for approval.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to update your older version with new Paid version then
  upload with same bundle ID and dont forgot to select in App purchase
  .
- if you do not want any change in older version (free version) then
  upload with new App id and Bundle Id .